# VB.Net - Delegates - High school level

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have an assignment that asks me to write a program that uses delegates and accepts two integers and prints the results for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. I honestly have no idea where to start, here's what I started with:

```
Imports System

Module Module1

    Private Delegate Sub MyDelegate()
    Sub Main()
        Dim Fns As MyDelegate
        Fns = New MyDelegate(AddressOf FnAdd)
        Fns()
        Fns = New MyDelegate(AddressOf FnSubtract)
        Fns()
        Fns = New MyDelegate(AddressOf FnMultiply)
        Fns()
        Fns = New MyDelegate(AddressOf FnDivide)
        Fns()
    End Sub
```

And this is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to bring the user input values into it, and nothing i try is working. Obviously I'm not very close, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `FnAdd`, `FnSubtract`, `FnMultiply` and `FnDivide` must take input parameters, i.e. the two integers for them to compute the sum or difference. And while calling `Fns` call it thus:

```
Fns(int param1, int param2) //Where param1 and param2 come from user input, may be a textbox or something
```

The important thing to note is that your delegate must match the input parameters of the method that it encompasses both in their data types and their number.